# Grammatically correct plural / singular endings

Tags: angular

Using a for loop, I have created a counter for late items by looping through items retrieved in a web request, setting a property of `late` as `true` if conditions are met, and incrementing the counter.

Using `*ngIf`, I could do the following:

```
<h5 *ngIf="lateCount != 1">You have {{lateCount}} late items.</h5>
<h5 *ngIf="lateCount == 1">You have {{lateCount}} late item.</h5>
```

Is there a way to do this without two `*ngIf`s?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [NgPlural](https://angular.io/api/common/NgPlural):

```
<h5>
  You have {{lateCount}} late

  <ng-container [ngPlural]="lateCount">
    <ng-template ngPluralCase="=1">item.</ng-template>
    <ng-template ngPluralCase="other">items.</ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</h5>
```

**Original answer (before NgPlural)**

Well you can trigger only `s` symbol on condition:

```
<h5>You have {{lateCount}} late item<ng-container *ngIf="lateCount == 1">s</ng-container>.</h5>
```

Another approach would be to write a pipe that does this for you, or furthermore, you can use Angular i18n (any other library) that provides the functionality to work with pluralization.

Comment: Adding a `s` does not cover for all your words. You have to have a map for all the possible singular/plural words and do the transforms in a pipe.

Comment: @PeterHuang of course it wouldn't and this answer never pretended to become a general approach. However as a quick and dirty thing this was not that bad for the time it was answered

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a bit late, but there's a neater way to solve the problem, with pipes.

[Here](https://github.com/andresgardiol/angular-plural-singular-custom-pipe) you can learn how to use it, it's really simple and reusable:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
      name: 'pluralSingular'
})
export class PluralSingularPipe implements PipeTransform {
        transform(number: number, singularText: string, pluralText: string = null): string {
      let pluralWord = pluralText ? pluralText : `${singularText}s`;
                return number > 1 ? `${number} ${pluralWord}` : `${number} ${singularText}`;
     }
}
```

Usage:

```html
{{ someNumberVariable | pluralSingular:'city':'cities }}
```

Comment: in my opinion, this answer is the better solution

Answer (score 3):

I know this question was asked a lot of time ago, but just to complete the argument there's another way you can accomplish the given task and that's by using the `ngPlural` directive.

Primarily `ngPlural` directive adds/removes DOM elements based on a numeric values

The `ngPlural` directive is very handy and can be used with the Common Locale Data Repository ([CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/cldr-spec/plural-rules)) defined category matches such as: one, few or many. As from the angular documentation you can use the directive as follows:

```js
<some-element [ngPlural]="value">
    <ng-template ngPluralCase="=0">there is nothing</ng-template>
    <ng-template ngPluralCase="=1">there is one</ng-template>
    <ng-template ngPluralCase="few">there are a few</ng-template>
</some-element>
```

For more information about the directive please see [ngPlural](https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/ngplural/).
Hope it helps :)

Comment: How is ngplural better than ngIf... Why not use ngIf instead ?

Answer (score 1):

As the answer below says you can use [NgPlural](https://angular.io/api/common/NgPlural)

Your template should look like:

```
<h5 [ngPlural]="lateCount">
  You have {{lateCount}} late
  <ng-template ngPluralCase="=1">item.</ng-template>
  <ng-template ngPluralCase="other">items.</ng-template>
</h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we should be doing if/else logic on English plural words.
Let's make a smart **suffix** pipe instead.

1. This pipe runs logic on plural words, defaulting to `s`.
2. Optionally add a replacement plural **suffix** like `ies`. Then words ending in `y` are replaced with `ies`.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13-template?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fplural.pipe.ts)

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'plural',
})
export class PluralPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(word: string, count: number, pluralForm: string = 's'): string {
    let transformed;
    // 'ies' vs singular 'y' (city / cities)
    if (pluralForm === 'ies') {
      // replace y with ies
      transformed = count != 1 ? word.replace(/.$/, pluralForm) : word;
    } else {
      // default to plural 's' (applicant / applicants)
      transformed = count === 1 ? word : word + pluralForm;
    }

    // console.log(count, word, transformed);
    return transformed;
  }
}
```

Basic usage (`s` is default)

```
{{ 'comment' | plural: 2 }} // comments
```

Advanced usage (`ies` for plural replaces words ending in `y`)

```
{{ 'reply' | plural: 3:'ies' }} // replies
```

Comment: This is now a available in Angular as `I18nPluralPipe`: https://angular.io/api/common/I18nPluralPipe

Comment: Does it handle `ies` vs `y` and `s`? Doesnt appear so but there's no working example in that doc.

Comment: No, it only handles simple cases and is not configurable for different plural forms. In that case you need to roll your own pipe, as you already demonstrated.